# How to stop apps from self installing

Tags: applications, security, malware

I have a problem for quite some time now. An app called xeroxservice which does not have any icon except that of apps like Google framework etc keeps downloading and installing itself without permission and notification. I can locate the apk in download folder. If I Uninstall it, it downloads another apk and install itself. It is surprising that  unknown source is unchecked and play store automatic update turned off. Virus scan doesn't detect anything and my device is not rooted. I Uninstalled all bloatwares and even stock browser with adb. Is there a way I can handle this it without factory reset? Thanks friends

Comment: Do you have a Xerox smartphone?

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] your question and include what device you're using and what Android version it is running. Apart from that, have you seen the questions linked in the "related" section of this page? Examples of related questions with answers: [Unwanted apps auto installing without me doing anything. How to stop them?](/q/175494/16575) // [Apps trying to install in background](/q/143549/16575) // [Unwanted android apps keep reinstalling](/q/144289/16575)

Comment: Thanks so much. I went through related questions but thought my question is different because 1) installation from unknown source is unchecked 2) automatic update turned off 3) device not rooted 4) all manufacturer apps that are bloatware to me have been completely Uninstalled for the current user with adb. But this app the apk somehow is always being downloaded and silently installed. My device is an MTN L860 running stock 6.0